# How to use TabHost.OnTabChangeListener in android?

Tags: android

How to use TabHost.OnTabChangeListener in android?

give me some example code... :(

thanks

Answer (score 76, accepted):

why it would be my pleasure to help you good sir:

```
myTabHost.setOnTabChangedListener(new OnTabChangeListener(){
@Override
public void onTabChanged(String tabId) {
    if(TAB_1_TAG.equals(tabId)) {
        //destroy earth
    }
    if(TAB_2_TAG.equals(tabId)) {
        //destroy mars
    }
}});
```

Where `TAB_1_TAG` is the tag provided to the `newTabSpec` method when creating the tab.

Comment: Thanks for the help, and I LOL'd so hard on
// destroy earth
and
// destroy mars

Comment: @pgsandstrom first of all, thanks a milion! there is so little on TabHost methods online at all. this really saved me. my only confusion is why the method call is `setOnTabChangedListener`, but it instantiates as `OnTabChangeListener()`. there is no "d" in the instantiation! hmm ;)

Answer (score 7):

I think in many cases it makes sense to make your TabActivity the listener:

```
public class MyTabActivity extends TabActivity implements OnTabChangeListener {

    private TabHost tabHost;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        /* Your onCreate code here */

        tabHost.setOnTabChangedListener(this);
    }

    /* ... */

    @Override
    public void onTabChanged(String tabId) {
        /* Your code to handle tab changes */
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `OnTabSelectedListener`,
here is an example.

```
  tabLayout.addOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
            switch (tab.getText().toString()) {
                case "yourTabTitle":
                    //todo your code
                    break;
            }
        }
        @Override
        public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
            switch (tab.getText().toString()) {
                case "yourTabTitle":
                    //todo your code
                    break;
            }
        }
        @Override
        public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
            switch (tab.getText().toString()) {
                case "yourTabTitle":
                    //todo your code
                    break;
            }
        }
    });
```