# Video playback problem in tab group activity of android?

Tags: android, android-layout

I have four tabs in my application , i play the video in first tab using video view and at the same time if i launch 3rd tab without stopping video in first tab , then i play another video in 3rd tab inside video view , both are different video view with different id and in different activity, but it seems to be overlap with video of first tab .

i need to close the activity while user move out another tab, how can i done that.If anyone knows means please help me out.

Thanks.

Comment: try onPause method in child activity .

Answer (score 0):

Did you try using onTabChangeListener.

[check this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2243360/how-to-use-tabhost-ontabchangelistener-in-android)