# android : save fields value of tab while changing tabs

Tags: android, tabs, sharedpreferences

I have an `Activity A` with 2 tabs and each tab have its own `Activity (B and C)` . `Activity B` and `Activity C`  each  have 2 text fields . I want to save value of these text field in `SharedPreferences` when user changes tabs.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

What you probably want is save your activity state in `onSaveInstanceState` instead, like this:

```
@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
  super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
  outState.putString(MY_KEY, myStringValue);
  // ...
}
```

And then in onCreate:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

  // other stuff...

  if(savedInstanceState != null) {
      myStringValue = savedInstanceState.getString(MY_KEY);
  }

}
```

Comment: @my android: You might also like to know about [TabHost.OnTabChangeListener](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2243360/593709)

Comment: onTabChangeListner will be called only in Activity A but i want to save field value of activity B and C. so how would i save field value of B and C in calling method of A